# Python: get a value count at various dict depths

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I'm trying to define a function that will allow me to get a value count at various levels of a dict.  For example, if I have something like:

```
vehicles = {
    'Ford': {
        'Falcon': {
            '2008': 10, 
            '2009': 12, 
            '2010': 5
        }
    }, 
    'Holden': {
        'Commodore': {
            '2008': 15, 
            '2009': 11, 
            '2010': 5
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to call a function that will calculate the values at each depth.  So at depth 0, the function would return the sum of every value (58).  At depth 1, the function would return a dict with `{'Ford':  27, 'Holden': 31}`.  At depth 2, the function would return a dict with `{'Ford': {'Falcon': 27}, 'Holden': {'Commodore': 31}}`. Etc...

I think I need to burrow to the max depth and start summing the values as I move back up the levels, but I'm fairly new to Python and I'm struggling.  Possibly I would need to use recursion?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution, not thoroughly tested

```
def sum_values(data):
    if type(data.values()[0]) != dict:
        return sum(data.values())
    else:
        return sum(sum_values(v) for v in data.values())

def depth_values(data, depth = 0):
    if depth == 0:
        return sum_values(data)
    else:
        return dict(
            (k, depth_values(v, depth-1))
            for k, v in data.items()
        )
```

TEST:

```
print depth_values(vehicles, 0) # >> 58
print depth_values(vehicles, 1) # >> {'Holden': 31, 'Ford': 27}
print depth_values(vehicles, 2) # >> {'Holden': {'Commodore': 31}, 'Ford': {'Falcon': 27}}
print depth_values(vehicles, 3) # exceptions
```

Comment: Instead of if-else in sum_values, I'd suggest try-except: `try: return sum(data.itervalues()) except TypeError: return sum(...)`  It looks nicer to me, and will not break if the input becomes some other object that behaves like a dict but isn't (e.g. defaultdict)

Comment: @happydave: yes that is right. there are several ways to make it more defensive. And Ned Batchelder is also quite interesting to me because I think of the problem as two tasks (sum-values and reach-to-a-depth). Ned Batchelder put the two tasks into one in his solution. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick, although I cheat a little and do type checking (which is just about as unpythonic as you can get), plus I am assuming that there are only ints and keys in the dictionary.  I will note that this approach works with unevenly distributed trees.

```
def score(n):
    if type(n) == int:
        return n
    else:
        return sum([score(n[x]) for x in n])

def fold_dict(xs, d):
    if d == 1:
        if type(xs) == int:
            return xs            
        return {n: score(xs[n]) for n in xs}
    else:
        if type(xs) == int:
            return xs    
        return {n: fold_dict(xs[n], d - 1) for n in xs}
```

Example input, output:

```
>>> y = {'a': {'a1': {'a11': 5, 'a12': 2, 'a13': 8}, 'a2': 6}, 'b': 7, 'c': {'c1': 18, 'c2': 1}}
>>> fold_dict(y, 1)
{'a': 21, 'c': 19, 'b': 7}
>>> fold_dict(y, 2)
{'a': {'a1': 15, 'a2': 6}, 'c': {'c2': 1, 'c1': 18}, 'b': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check dictionary's max depth, as using `isinstance` and `recursion`

for example,

```
depth = 0
dict = { ... }
def find_depth(dict):
    # dict = { ... }
    for key in dict:
        if isinstance(dict[key], dict):
            depth += 1
            find_depth(dict[key])
            break
```

Comment: Cheers @admire.  I should have mentioned that I can find the max depth by using a function like yours (that I found in another post).  It's the next step I'm struggling with.  That is, how to work backwards from the max depth.

Answer (score 0):

```
def values_at_depth(d, depth):
    if depth == 0:
        sum = 0
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            if hasattr(v, "keys"):
                sum += values_at_depth(v, 0)
            else:
                sum += v
        return sum
    else:
        ret = {}
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            ret[k] = values_at_depth(v, depth-1)
        return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, I modified @Ned Batchelder 's function to return a tuple that, in addition to reporting the sum of the values, also reportss the number of keys at various depths.  Hopefully that made sense...

Anyway, here it is:

```
def values_at_depth(d, depth = 0):
    if depth == 0:
        sumVal = 0
        sumKey = 0
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            if hasattr(v, "keys"):
                sumKey += collectCnt(v, 0)[0]
                sumVal += collectCnt(v, 0)[1]
            else:
                sumVal += v
                sumKey += 1
        return (sumKey,sumVal)
    else:
        ret = {}
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            ret[k] = collectCnt(v, depth-1)
        return ret
```

PS. I was not sure where to put this extra info.  If it should be somewhere else please let me know.